# Rails Activerecord querying has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Need some help with Activerecord Querying in a has_many :through association.

Model:

**Job**

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :job_metadata, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :metadata, :through => :job_metadata
```

**Metadatum**

```
class Metadatum < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :metadata_type_id
  has_one :metadatum_type
  has_many :job_metadata, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :jobs, :through => :job_metadata
```

**MetadatumType**

```
class MetadatumType < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description
  has_many :metada
```

**JobMetadatum**

```
class JobMetadatum < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :job_id, :metadatum_id
  belongs_to :job
  belongs_to :metadatum
```

In the console, I can run:

```
@job.metadata
```

which returns

```
=> [#<Metadatum id: 2, description: "Part Time", metadatum_type_id: 1, created_at: "2012-06-23 20:42:14", updated_at: "2012-06-23 20:42:14">]
```

But how would I return the metadatum_id on @jobs.metadata which have a **metadatum_type_id** = 1?

I'm trying this:

```
@job.metadata.metadatum_id.where('metadata.metadatum_type_id' => 1)
```

But getting the following error:

```
NoMethodError:   Metadatum Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "metadata".* FROM 
"metadata" INNER JOIN "job_metadata" ON "metadata"."id" = 
"job_metadata"."metadatum_id" WHERE "job_metadata"."job_id" = 31
undefined method `metadatum_id' 
for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007f7fb3188de8>
```

Comment: The most critical thing about has_any :through is to actually get the model names right initially.  Metadata and metadatum are very non-englishy.  I would come up with better names first.  I've learned this from experience myself.

Comment: Thank you Michael. I'd love suggestions for what to name these models given what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
@the_metadatum_record = @job.metadata.where("metadatum_type_id = 1").first
```

This searches through the Metadatum records that belong to @job, and looks through those records to find ones that have metadatum_type_id of 1.

Then the id can be accessed like `@the_metadatum_record.id`

The "first" is added to the end because if your job has more than one metadatum of type 1, the query will return all of them.

Also, I agree with Michael, those are kind of terrible names for tables...

Comment: Thank you. What would you recommend for the naming convention. These tables can essentially store data related to the Job of different types. Hoping to avoid lots of individual table relationships for each data type (Job Type, Category, Industry, etc.) with this architecture. But open to a better naming convention!!

Comment: well, if every job will have a job type, category, and industry, I would add all those as columns to your jobs table. Otherwise, you could maybe make a Detail model, or even JobDetail. That way when you query for things like the metadata record id, it would look like `@job.job_details.where("job_detail_type =1")`. It's just more readable that way